# How can I pad a value with leading zeros?

Tags: javascript, leading-zero, zerofill

What is the recommended way to zerofill a value in JavaScript? I imagine I could build a custom function to pad zeros on to a typecasted value, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way to do this?

**Note:** By "zerofilled" I mean it in the database sense of the word (where a 6-digit zerofilled representation of the number 5 would be "000005").

Comment: This really isn't enough information to answer.  The most common instance of "zero padding" is probably probably prepending zeroes onto dates: 5/1/2008 > 05/01/2008.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: For node apps, use `npm install sprintf-js`, and require it in the file you need: `sprintf('%0d6', 5);`

Comment: `function padWithZeroes(n, width) { while(n.length<width) n = '0' + n; return n;}`   ...assuming `n` not negative

Comment: @Paolo that function doesn't work if n is numeric. You'd need to convert n to a String before the `while` in order to access `n.length`

Comment: @NickF of course... and assuming 'n' is a string.

Comment: This question's title [used to be](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1267283/revisions) `How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?` and is linked as such by the many duplicates.

Comment: One liner without Math or While loops or libraries?
`mynum = "0".repeat((n=6-mynum.toString().length)>0?n:0)+mynum;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a JavaScript function that can pad a string to get to a determined length?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2686855/90527)

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Since ECMAScript 2017 we have [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
const padded = (.1 + "").padStart(6, "0");
console.log(`-${padded}`);
```

#### Before ECMAScript 2017

With [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
var n=-0.1;
var res = n.toLocaleString('en', {minimumIntegerDigits:4,minimumFractionDigits:2,useGrouping:false});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Could also be `String(.1).padStart(6, "0");`

Answer (score 497):

I can't believe all the complex answers on here... Just use this:

```
var zerofilled = ('0000'+n).slice(-4);
```

```js
let n = 1
var zerofilled = ('0000'+n).slice(-4);
console.log(zerofilled)
```

Comment: function zpad(x, zeros){
    var length = Math.max((""+x).length, zeros);
    return (repeat('0', length) + x).slice(-length);
}

Comment: Good except for negative numbers and numbers longer than 4 digits.

Comment: @wberry this was not intended to be production ready code, but more a simple explanation of the basics to solving the question at hand. Aka it's very easy to determine if a number is positive or negative and add the appropriate sign if needed, so i didn't want to cluster my easy example with that. Also, it's just as easy to make a function taking a digit length as an arg and using that instead of my hardcoded values.

Comment: @Seaux, you said: _"can't believe all the complex answers"_, and then started explaining yourself the complexity when commented. This means you understand that there are perspectives from which your answer is not perfect. Hence the complexity.

Comment: @OmShankar by "complex answers", I wasn't referring to explained or detailed answers (which are obviously encouraged on this site even though my answer isn't), but rather answers that contained unnecessary code complexity.

Comment: @Seaux, agreed, however, the complexity mentioned is not "unnecessary" - it's a consideration of other factors which is important.

Comment: @OmShankar, on some/most sure, but even look at the accepted answer -- It had to make a special note at the top addressing its performance issues. My solution is a single js function that will handle easily 90% of this guys, and most, conditions.

Comment: @wberry, this answer could be adapted to allow bigger numbers as var zerofilled = ('0000'+n).slice(-Math.max(4, n.length));

Comment: I like this answer. In my own specific case, I know that the numbers are always positive and never more than 3 digits, and this is often the case when you're padding with leading 0's and your input is well known. Nice!

Comment: `('000'+n).slice(-4)`

Comment: `(n < 0 ? '-' : '') + ('0000'+Math.abs(n)).slice(-4);`

Comment: @Seaux You undermined your point about unneeded complexity by providing an answer that was too simple to be correct.

Answer (score 346):

Simple way. You could add string multiplication for the pad and turn it into a function.

```
var pad = "000000";
var n = '5';
var result = (pad+n).slice(-pad.length);
```

As a function,

```
function paddy(num, padlen, padchar) {
    var pad_char = typeof padchar !== 'undefined' ? padchar : '0';
    var pad = new Array(1 + padlen).join(pad_char);
    return (pad + num).slice(-pad.length);
}
var fu = paddy(14, 5); // 00014
var bar = paddy(2, 4, '#'); // ###2
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, best I've seen.  For clarity, here's a simpler version I'm using to pad the minutes in time formatting:

    ('0'+minutes).slice(-2)

Comment: This is 5 times slower than the implementation with a while loop: https://gist.github.com/4382935

Comment: @superjoe30 it's not reasonable to include Math.Random in your benchmark loop

Comment: This has a **FATAL FLAW** with larger than expected numbers -- which is an extremely common occurrence.  For example, `paddy (888, 2)` yields `88` and not `888` as required.  This answer also does not handle negative numbers.

Comment: @BrockAdams, zerofill is typically used for fixed width number/formatting cases -- therefore I think it'd actually be less likely (or even a non-issue) if given a 3 digit number when trying to do 2 digit zerofill.

Comment: ("000000" + somenum).substr(-6,6) where the number of zeros and the -6,6 correspond to the pad width. Same idea but slice take one less param; not sure if slice is faster or slower than subtr. Of course my solution isn't needing variable assignment.

Comment: I added the ECMA 2017 solution to jsperf - it's faster in Chrome/FF than the homegrown solutions: https://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad/27

Comment: ECMAScript 2017
var newValue = string.padStart(10 , '0');
console.log("value after Padding is : " + string.padStart(10 , '0'));

Answer (score 119):

I actually had to come up with something like this recently.
I figured there had to be a way to do it without using loops.

This is what I came up with.

```
function zeroPad(num, numZeros) {
    var n = Math.abs(num);
    var zeros = Math.max(0, numZeros - Math.floor(n).toString().length );
    var zeroString = Math.pow(10,zeros).toString().substr(1);
    if( num < 0 ) {
        zeroString = '-' + zeroString;
    }

    return zeroString+n;
}
```

Then just use it providing a number to zero pad:

```
> zeroPad(50,4);
"0050"
```

If the number is larger than the padding, the number will expand beyond the padding:

```
> zeroPad(51234, 3);
"51234"
```

Decimals are fine too!

```
> zeroPad(51.1234, 4);
"0051.1234"
```

If you don't mind polluting the global namespace you can add it to Number directly:

```
Number.prototype.leftZeroPad = function(numZeros) {
    var n = Math.abs(this);
    var zeros = Math.max(0, numZeros - Math.floor(n).toString().length );
    var zeroString = Math.pow(10,zeros).toString().substr(1);
    if( this < 0 ) {
        zeroString = '-' + zeroString;
    }

    return zeroString+n;
}
```

And if you'd rather have decimals take up space in the padding:

```
Number.prototype.leftZeroPad = function(numZeros) {
    var n = Math.abs(this);
    var zeros = Math.max(0, numZeros - n.toString().length );
    var zeroString = Math.pow(10,zeros).toString().substr(1);
    if( this < 0 ) {
        zeroString = '-' + zeroString;
    }

    return zeroString+n;
}
```

Cheers!

---

---

[XDR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2030088/xdr) came up with **a logarithmic variation** that seems to perform better.

**WARNING**: This function fails if num equals zero (e.g. zeropad(0, 2))

```
function zeroPad (num, numZeros) {
    var an = Math.abs (num);
    var digitCount = 1 + Math.floor (Math.log (an) / Math.LN10);
    if (digitCount >= numZeros) {
        return num;
    }
    var zeroString = Math.pow (10, numZeros - digitCount).toString ().substr (1);
    return num < 0 ? '-' + zeroString + an : zeroString + an;
}
```

---

Speaking of performance, [tomsmeding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1608468/tomsmeding) [compared the top 3 answers](http://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad) ([4 with the log variation](http://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad/10)).  Guess which one *majorly* outperformed the other two? :)

Comment: This is good, I like how it's readable and robust. The only thing I would change is the name of the `numZeros` parameter, since it's misleading. It's not the number of zeros you want to add, it's the minimum length the number should be. A better name would be `numLength` or even `length`.

Comment: +1. Unlike the higher voted answers, this one handles negative numbers and does not return gross errors on overflow!!?!

Comment: Performance measure amongst three top answers here: http://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad

Comment: I improved the performance of this answer by over 100% by using logarithms.  Please see the logarithmic test case at [http://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad/10](http://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad/10)

Comment: The original solution is better, logarithmic variation doesn't work if `num` can be zero...

Comment: @OndraC. I just noticed the same thing today, nice catch.  It is due to the `digitCount`.  I reverted to the original but users could add a check for zero and set `digitCount` to 1 in that case.

Comment: Its really easy to avoid the failure for zeroPad(0, 100). You can see it at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/littlefyr/g6d4yn5v/, but the fix is is, `if (num == 0){return Math.pow(10, numZeros).toString().substr(1);}`

Comment: ?? `Math.pow(10, n)` will return a value that will be represented with scientific notation for large values of `n`, and this will therefore fail.

Answer (score 90):

Modern browsers now support [`padStart`](http://www.2ality.com/2015/11/string-padding.html), you can simply now do:

```
string.padStart(maxLength, "0");
```

Example:

```js
string = "14";
maxLength = 5; // maxLength is the max string length, not max # of fills
res = string.padStart(maxLength, "0");
console.log(res); // prints "00014"

number = 14;
maxLength = 5; // maxLength is the max string length, not max # of fills
res = number.toString().padStart(maxLength, "0");
console.log(res); // prints "00014"
```

Answer (score 87):

Here's what I used to pad a number up to 7 characters.

```
("0000000" + number).slice(-7)
```

This approach will probably suffice for most people.

Edit: If you want to make it more generic you can do this:

```
("0".repeat(padding) + number).slice(-padding)
```

Edit 2: Note that since ES2017 you can use `String.prototype.padStart`:

```
number.toString().padStart(padding, "0")
```

Comment: This fails, badly, on large numbers and negative numbers.  `number = 123456789`, with the code, above, for example.

Comment: This solution is the best possible ever for certains scenarios! I've got no clue why we didn't come up with this before. The scenario is: you've got a number which is always positive [as Brock mentioned] and you know that it won't take more characters than your limit. In our case we have a score which we store in Amazon SDB. As you know SDB can't compare numbers, so all scores have to be zero padded. This is extremely easy and effective!

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that this won't work for negative numbers. I think this deals with the more common positive number case, though. It does what I need, at least!

Comment: Needed this again and realised you don't need `new String`. You can just use string literals.

Comment: this works great for keeping the leading zeros in US zip codes.

Comment: Very useful when you know what you are getting (expecting longer number/string adjust the slice) and what you are expecting. Why we are talking about numbers, 1 and 0001 are the same. We only need to pad leading 0 in strings.

Comment: `(new Array(padding + 1).join("0")` can be replaced with `"0".repeat(padding)`

Comment: Nice! Thanks, @Pavel. Updated my answer.

Comment: Nice solution the `padStart()`

Comment: Thanks. With this I managed to pad my index starting at 01 for when I needed to sort a column as string from within a foreach

`var done = ++index; var formatted = done.toString().padStart(2, "0")`

Answer (score 33):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of needless complicated suggestions for this problem, typically involving writing your own function to do math or string manipulation or calling a third-party utility.  However, there is a standard way of doing this in the base JavaScript library with just one line of code.  It might be worth wrapping this one line of code in a function to avoid having to specify parameters that you never want to change like the local name or style.

```
var amount = 5;

var text = amount.toLocaleString('en-US',
{
    style: 'decimal',
    minimumIntegerDigits: 3,
    useGrouping: false
});
```

This will produce the value of "005" for text.  You can also use the toLocaleString function of Number to pad zeros to the right side of the decimal point.

```
var amount = 5;

var text = amount.toLocaleString('en-US',
{
    style: 'decimal',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    useGrouping: false
});
```

This will produce the value of "5.00" for text.  Change useGrouping to true to use comma separators for thousands.

Note that using `toLocaleString()` with `locales` and `options` arguments [is standardized separately in ECMA-402](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-13.2.1), not in ECMAScript. As of today, some browsers [only implement basic support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility), i.e. `toLocaleString()` may ignore any arguments.

[Complete Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w3xgqmsr/)

Comment: Wow, this is a super clean solution and works in node.js.

Comment: I chuckled when I read the intro -- "needless complicated suggestions".
Software development, as in all engineering disciplines, involves weighing trade-offs.   I tried this "standard way" myself -- and timed it.  It definitely works, but I would never choose to use it for any kind of repetitive application due to how slow it is compared to many of the other "home rolled" solutions.

Comment: True, a lot of built-in JavaScript functions perform poorly when looping over lots of data, but I would argue you should not use JavaScript for that, even server-side like Node.js.  If you have lots of data to process server-side, you should use a better platform like .NET or Java.  If you are processing client-side data for display to the end user, you should only process the data for what you are currently rendering to the end user's screen. For example, render only the visible rows of a table and don't process data for other roads.

Comment: this appears to solve the entirely different problem of formatting numbers to a specific number of decimal places (`5` becomes `5.00`). the question above is seeking a way to zero pad a number (`5` becomes `005`).

Answer (score 21):

If the fill number is known in advance not to exceed a certain value, there's another way to do this with no loops:

```
var fillZeroes = "00000000000000000000";  // max number of zero fill ever asked for in global

function zeroFill(number, width) {
    // make sure it's a string
    var input = number + "";  
    var prefix = "";
    if (input.charAt(0) === '-') {
        prefix = "-";
        input = input.slice(1);
        --width;
    }
    var fillAmt = Math.max(width - input.length, 0);
    return prefix + fillZeroes.slice(0, fillAmt) + input;
}
```

Test cases here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/N87mZ/

Comment: @BrockAdams - fixed for both cases you mention.  If the number is already as wide as the fill width, then no fill is added.

Comment: Thanks; +1.  The negative numbers are slightly off from the usual convention, though.  In your test case, `-88` should yield `"-00088"`, for example.

Comment: @BrockAdams - I wasn't sure whether calling `zeroFill(-88, 5)` should produce `-00088` or `-0088`?  I guess it depends upon whether you want the `width` argument to be the entire width of the number or just the number of digits (not including the negative sign).  An implementer can easily switch the behavior to not include the negative sign by just removing the `--width` line of code.

Answer (score 20):

The quick and dirty way:

```
y = (new Array(count + 1 - x.toString().length)).join('0') + x;
```

For x = 5 and count = 6 you'll have y = "000005"

Comment: I got `y="0005"` with the above, `y = (new Array(count + 1 - x.toString().length)).join('0') + x;` is what gave me `y="000005"`

Comment: @OrrSiloni: the shortest code solution is actually `('0000'+n).slice(-4)`

Answer (score 17):

Here's a quick function I came up with to do the job. If anyone has a simpler approach, feel free to share!

```
function zerofill(number, length) {
    // Setup
    var result = number.toString();
    var pad = length - result.length;

    while(pad > 0) {
        result = '0' + result;
        pad--;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there will be a "simpler" solution - it will always be a function of some sort.  We could have a algorithm discussion, but at the end of the day, you'll still end up with a function that zerofills a number.

Comment: My general advice is to use "for" loops as they are generally more stable and faster in ECMAScript languages (ActionScript 1-3, and JavaScript)

Comment: Or, skip iteration altogether ;)

Comment: Simpler function? Probably not. One that doesn't loop? That is possible... though the algorithm isn't entirely trivial.

Comment: Wow, pretty much all the above comments are incorrect.  @profitehlolz's solution is simpler and suitable for inlining (doesn't need to be a function).
Meanwhile, `for` .vs. `while` performance is not different enough to be interesting: http://jsperf.com/fors-vs-while/34

Comment: I'd argue that @profiteholz's solution is far from simple in terms of how I understood "simple" being used in this context. Given all of the possible meanings there's a chance both of our interpretations are wrong. :P

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers: 
`zerofill(-23, 5)` gives `00-23`, which is a bit icky.

Comment: Nice! Could be simplified: var result = number.toString(); while(result.length < length){result = '0' + result}; return result

Answer (score 17):

ECMAScript 2017:
use **padStart** or **padEnd**

```
'abc'.padStart(10);         // "       abc"
'abc'.padStart(10, "foo");  // "foofoofabc"
'abc'.padStart(6,"123465"); // "123abc"
```

More info:

- https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-pad-start-end
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 14):

I often use this construct for doing ad-hoc padding of some value `n`, known to be a positive, decimal:

```
(offset + n + '').substr(1);
```

Where `offset` is 10^^digits.

E.g., padding to 5 digits, where n = 123:

```
(1e5 + 123 + '').substr(1); // => 00123
```

The hexadecimal version of this is slightly more verbose:

```
(0x100000 + 0x123).toString(16).substr(1); // => 00123
```

Note 1: I like @profitehlolz's solution as well, which is the string version of this, using slice()'s nifty negative-index feature.

Comment: Wow.  Short and elegant.

Answer (score 13):

I really don't know why, but no one did it in the most obvious way. Here it's my implementation.

Function:

```
/** Pad a number with 0 on the left */
function zeroPad(number, digits) {
    var num = number+"";
    while(num.length < digits){
        num='0'+num;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Prototype:

```
Number.prototype.zeroPad=function(digits){
    var num=this+"";
    while(num.length < digits){
        num='0'+num;
    }
    return(num);
};
```

Very straightforward, I can't see any way how this can be any simpler. For some reason I've seem many times here on SO, people just try to avoid 'for' and 'while' loops at any cost. Using regex will probably cost way more cycles for such a trivial 8 digit padding.

Answer (score 13):

I use this snippet to get a five-digits representation:

```
(value+100000).toString().slice(-5) // "00123" with value=123
```

Comment: just what the doctor ordered!!

Answer (score 12):

In all modern browsers you can use

```
numberStr.padStart(numberLength, "0");
```

```js
function zeroFill(num, numLength) {
  var numberStr = num.toString();

  return numberStr.padStart(numLength, "0");
}

var numbers = [0, 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345];

numbers.forEach(
  function(num) {
    var numString = num.toString();
    
    var paddedNum = zeroFill(numString, 5);

    console.log(paddedNum);
  }
);
```

Here is the MDN reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 10):

The power of Math!

x = integer to pad
y = number of zeroes to pad

```
function zeroPad(x, y)
{
   y = Math.max(y-1,0);
   var n = (x / Math.pow(10,y)).toFixed(y);
   return n.replace('.','');  
}
```

Comment: While it certainly works, and math is extremely reliable, I would have preferred an extremely verbose write n the approach taken here.  What function is this?

Answer (score 9):

Don't reinvent the wheel; use [underscore string](https://esamattis.github.io/underscore.string/#pad-str-length-padstr-type-gt-string):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/ob6fnh1e/)

```
var numToPad = '5';

alert(_.str.pad(numToPad, 6, '0')); // Yields: '000005'
```

Comment: What is the overhead? Importing 2000 functions to use one of them?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, depending on the conditions and constraints, that could be a sound decision. However, with proper tree shaking in your build tool you automatically shed the other 1999 unused functions in your release anyway.

Answer (score 9):

This is the ES6 solution.

```js
function pad(num, len) {
  return '0'.repeat(len - num.toString().length) + num;
}
alert(pad(1234,6));
```

Comment: Clearly the most elegant solution I would just modify it to avoid 2 string conversions: `const numStr = String(num)` and `return '0'.repeat(len - numStr.length) + numStr;`

Answer (score 9):

Not that this question needs more answers, but I thought I would add the simple lodash version of this.

`_.padLeft(number, 6, '0')`

Comment: Better: `var zfill = _.partialRight(_.padStart, '0');`

Comment: Some people will probably protest "I don't want to use lodash" but it's hardly a valid argument anymore since you can install only this function: `npm install --save lodash.padleft`, then `import padLeft from 'lodash.padleft'` and omit the `_.`

Answer (score 9):

I didn't see anyone point out the fact that when you use [String.prototype.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) with a negative number it counts from the right.

A one liner solution to the OP's question, a 6-digit zerofilled representation of the number 5, is:

```js
console.log(("00000000" + 5).substr(-6));
```

Generalizing we'll get:

```js
function pad(num, len) { return ("00000000" + num).substr(-len) };

console.log(pad(5, 6));
console.log(pad(45, 6));
console.log(pad(345, 6));
console.log(pad(2345, 6));
console.log(pad(12345, 6));
```

Answer (score 8):

After a, long, long time of testing 15 different functions/methods found in this questions answers, I now know which is the best (the most versatile and quickest).

I took 15 functions/methods from the answers to this question and made a script to measure the time taken to execute 100 pads. Each pad would pad the number `9` with `2000` zeros. This may seem excessive, and it is, but it gives you a good idea about the scaling of the functions.

The code I used can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/NextToNothing/6325915

Feel free to modify and test the code yourself.

In order to get the most versatile method, you have to use a loop. This is because with very large numbers others are likely to fail, whereas, this will succeed.

So, which loop to use? Well, that would be a `while` loop. A `for` loop is still fast, but a `while` loop is just slightly quicker(a couple of ms) - and cleaner.

Answers like those by `Wilco`, `Aleksandar Toplek` or `Vitim.us` will do the job perfectly.

Personally, I tried a different approach. I tried to use a recursive function to pad the string/number. It worked out better than methods joining an array but, still, didn't work as quick as a for loop.

My function is:

```
function pad(str, max, padder) {
  padder = typeof padder === "undefined" ? "0" : padder;
  return str.toString().length < max ? pad(padder.toString() + str, max, padder) : str;
}
```

You can use my function with, or without, setting the padding variable. So like this:

```
pad(1, 3); // Returns '001'
// - Or -
pad(1, 3, "x"); // Returns 'xx1'
```

Personally, after my tests, I would use a method with a while loop, like `Aleksandar Toplek` or `Vitim.us`. However, I would modify it slightly so that you are able to set the padding string.

So, I would use this code:

```
function padLeft(str, len, pad) {
    pad = typeof pad === "undefined" ? "0" : pad + "";
    str = str + "";
    while(str.length < len) {
        str = pad + str;
    }
    return str;
}

// Usage
padLeft(1, 3); // Returns '001'
// - Or -
padLeft(1, 3, "x"); // Returns 'xx1'
```

You could also use it as a prototype function, by using this code:

```
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(len, pad) {
    pad = typeof pad === "undefined" ? "0" : pad + "";
    var str = this + "";
    while(str.length < len) {
        str = pad + str;
    }
    return str;
}

// Usage
var num = 1;

num.padLeft(3); // Returns '001'
// - Or -
num.padLeft(3, "x"); // Returns 'xx1'
```

Comment: I put this in a jsfiddle to make it quick for others to test, adding your version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinmicke/vnvghw7y/2/ Your version is always very competitive, and sometimes the fastest. Thanks for the fairly exhaustive testing.

Answer (score 8):

First parameter is any real number, second parameter is a positive integer specifying the minimum number of digits to the left of the decimal point and third parameter is an optional positive integer specifying the number if digits to the right of the decimal point.

```
function zPad(n, l, r){
    return(a=String(n).match(/(^-?)(\d*)\.?(\d*)/))?a[1]+(Array(l).join(0)+a[2]).slice(-Math.max(l,a[2].length))+('undefined'!==typeof r?(0<r?'.':'')+(a[3]+Array(r+1).join(0)).slice(0,r):a[3]?'.'+a[3]:''):0
}
```

so

```
           zPad(6, 2) === '06'
          zPad(-6, 2) === '-06'
       zPad(600.2, 2) === '600.2'
        zPad(-600, 2) === '-600'
         zPad(6.2, 3) === '006.2'
        zPad(-6.2, 3) === '-006.2'
      zPad(6.2, 3, 0) === '006'
        zPad(6, 2, 3) === '06.000'
    zPad(600.2, 2, 3) === '600.200'
zPad(-600.1499, 2, 3) === '-600.149'
```

Answer (score 7):

The latest way to do this is much simpler:

```
var number = 2
number.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits:2})
```

`output: "02"`

Comment: `(8).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 5})` returns `"00.008"` for me, based on my locale.

Answer (score 5):

Just another solution, but I think it's more legible.

```js
function zeroFill(text, size)
{
  while (text.length < size){
    text = "0" + text;
  }

  return text;
}
```

Comment: Same as which other?

Answer (score 4):

This one is less native, but may be the fastest...

```
zeroPad = function (num, count) {
    var pad = (num + '').length - count;
    while(--pad > -1) {
        num = '0' + num;
    }
    return num;
};
```

Comment: i think you want to do `pad = count - (num + '').length`. negative numbers aren't handled well, but apart from that, it's not bad. +1

Answer (score 4):

My solution

```
Number.prototype.PadLeft = function (length, digit) {
    var str = '' + this;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = (digit || '0') + str;
    }
    return str;
};
```

Usage

```
var a = 567.25;
a.PadLeft(10); // 0000567.25

var b = 567.25;
b.PadLeft(20, '2'); // 22222222222222567.25
```

Answer (score 4):

### With ES6+ JavaScript:

You can "zerofill a number" with something like the following function:

```js
/**
 * @param number The number
 * @param minLength Minimal length for your string with leading zeroes
 * @return Your formatted string
 */
function zerofill(nb, minLength) {
    // Convert your number to string.
    let nb2Str = nb.toString()

    // Guess the number of zeroes you will have to write.
    let nbZeroes = Math.max(0, minLength - nb2Str.length)

    // Compute your result.
    return `${ '0'.repeat(nbZeroes) }${ nb2Str }`
}

console.log(zerofill(5, 6))    // Displays "000005"
```

### With ES2017+:

```js
/**
 * @param number The number
 * @param minLength Minimal length for your string with leading zeroes
 * @return Your formatted string
 */
const zerofill = (nb, minLength) => nb.toString().padStart(minLength, '0')

console.log(zerofill(5, 6))    // Displays "000005"
```

Comment: Sweet! Esp. ES2017 version is very handy.

Answer (score 3):

The ***simplest***, most straight-forward solution you will find.

```
function zerofill(number,length) {
    var output = number.toString();
    while(output.length < length) {
      output = '0' + output;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use recursion:

```
function padZero(s, n) {
    s = s.toString(); // In case someone passes a number
    return s.length >= n ? s : padZero('0' + s, n);
}
```

Comment: padZero(223, 3) fails with '0223'

Comment: Well, I assumed that this function is called with a string as the first parameter. However, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Some monkeypatching also works

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function (n, c) {
  if (isNaN(n))
    return null;
  c = c || "0";
  return (new Array(n).join(c).substring(0, this.length-n)) + this; 
};
var paddedValue = "123".padLeft(6); // returns "000123"
var otherPadded = "TEXT".padLeft(8, " "); // returns "    TEXT"
```

Comment: -1 monkeypatching the toplevel namespacing in javascript is bad practice.

Comment: True for Object and Array objects, but String is not bad

Answer (score 2):

```
function pad(toPad, padChar, length){
    return (String(toPad).length < length)
        ? new Array(length - String(toPad).length + 1).join(padChar) + String(toPad)
        : toPad;
}
```

`pad(5, 0, 6)`      = `000005`

`pad('10', 0, 2)`   = `10  // don't pad if not necessary`

`pad('S', 'O', 2)`  = `SO`

...etc.

Cheers

Comment: I think it should be more like: `var s = String(toPad); return (s.length < length) ? new Array(length - s.length + 1).join('0') + s : s;` if you fix it I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: @drewish Thanks for catching that, I agree with your edit (except for the hardcoded `0` join char :) -- Answer updated.

Comment: I think it'd be better to store the string into a temporary variable. I did some benchmarking of that here: http://jsperf.com/padding-with-memoization it's also got benchmarks for the use of the new in "new Array" the results for new are all over the place but memiozation seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's my version of a pad function:

```
function pad(num, len) {
  return Array(len + 1 - num.toString().length).join('0') + num;
}
```

It also won't truncate numbers longer than the padding length

Answer (score 2):

If performance is really critical (looping over millions of records), an array of padding strings can be pre-generated, avoiding to do it for each call.

Time complexity: **O(1)**.
Space complexity: **O(1)**.

```js
const zeroPads = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, v) => '0'.repeat(v))

function zeroPad(num, len) {
  const numStr = String(num)
  return (zeroPads[len - numStr.length] + numStr)
}
```

Comment: Concatenating strings of variable length is performed in constant time and space? Which model of computation did you chose?

Answer (score 1):

This method isn't faster, but it's fairly native.

```
zeroPad = function (num, count) {
    return [Math.pow(10, count - num.toString().length), num].join('').substr(1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version :

```
function zPad(s,n){
    return (new Array(n+1).join('0')+s).substr(-Math.max(n,s.toString().length));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function zeroFill(number, width) {
    width -= (number.toString().length - /\./.test(number));
    if (width > 0) {
        return new Array(width + 1).join('0') + number;
    }
    return number + ""; // always return a string
}
```

Slight changes made to Peter's code. With his code if the input is (1.2, 3) the value returned should be 01.2 but it is returning 1.2.  The changes here should correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am to naive, but I think that this works in one simple and efficient line of code (for positive numbers):

```
padded = (value + Math.pow(10, total_length) + "").slice(1)
```

As long as you keep your length OK according to you set of values (as in any zero padding), this should work.

The steps are:

1. Add the power of 10 with the correct number of 0's [69+1000 = 1069]
2. Convert to string with +"" [1069 => "1069"]
3. Slice the first 1, which resulted of first multiplication ["1069" => "069"]

For natural listings (files, dirs...) is quite useful.

Comment: Doesn't work if a) your number is longer than the intended padding (1234 padded to length 3 becomes "234"; b) if `10^length > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (therefore length is limited to typically ~15); c) if `10^length` will be displayed in scientific notation (typically if length > 20).

Answer (score 1):

A simple one for my use case (to fill milliseconds never > 999)
You can adjust the number of zeros for yours or use a more generic way if required.

```
/**
 * @val integer
 * @zeros padding
 */
function zeroFill(val, zeros)
{
    var str = val.toString();
    if (str.length >= zeros)
        return str;
    str = "000" + str;
    return str.substring(str.length - zeros);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My little contribution with this topic (https://gist.github.com/lucasferreira/a881606894dde5568029):

```
/* Autor: Lucas Ferreira - http://blog.lucasferreira.com | Usage: fz(9) or fz(100, 7) */
function fz(o, s) {
    for(var s=Math.max((+s||2),(n=""+Math.abs(o)).length); n.length<s; (n="0"+n));
    return (+o < 0 ? "-" : "") + n;
};
```

Usage:

```
fz(9) & fz(9, 2) == "09"
fz(-3, 2) == "-03"
fz(101, 7) == "0000101"
```

I know, it's a pretty dirty function, but it's fast and works even with negative numbers ;)

Answer (score 1):

> **sprintf.js** is a complete open source JavaScript sprintf implementation
>   for the browser and node.js.
>
> Its prototype is simple:
>
> ```
> string sprintf(string format , [mixed arg1 [, mixed arg2 [ ,...]]])
> ```

I'd like to recommend [`sprintf` module](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js) from [Alexandru Mărășteanu](https://github.com/alexei) throughout the solution would simply looks like:

```
var sprintf = require('sprintf');
var zeroFilled = sprintf('%06d', 5);

console.log(zeroFilled); // 000005
```

> **Note:** I'm answering this question 6 years later but it seems that this
>   question becomes a "*javascript zero leading*" reference considering
>   it's high number of views and answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this simple approach

```
var input = 1000; //input any number
var len = input.toString().length;
for (i = 1; i < input; i++) {
  console.log("MyNumber_" + ('000000000000000' + i).slice(-len));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think my approach is a little different. The reason I needed to pad a number was to display it in a `<pre>` element (part of an on-screen log), so it's ultimately going to be a string anyway. Instead of doing any math, I wrote a simple function to overlay a string value on a mask string:

```
function overlayr(m, s) {
  return m.length > s.length ? m.substr(0, m.length - s.length) + s : s;
}
```

The benefit of this is that I can use it for all sorts of string alignment tasks. To call it, just pass in the mask and number as a string:

```
> overlayr('00000', (5).toString())
< "00005"
```

As an added bonus, it deals with overflows correctly:

```
> overlayr('00000', (555555).toString())
< "555555"
```

And of course it's not limited to 0 padding:

```
> overlayr('*****', (55).toString())
< "***55"
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any answer in this form so here my shot with regex and string manipulation

(Works also for **negative** and **decimal** numbers)

**Code:**

```
function fillZeroes(n = 0, m = 1) {
  const p = Math.max(1, m);
  return String(n).replace(/\d+/, x => '0'.repeat(Math.max(p - x.length, 0)) + x);
}
```

**Some outputs:**

```
console.log(fillZeroes(6, 2))          // >> '06'
console.log(fillZeroes(1.35, 2))       // >> '01.35'
console.log(fillZeroes(-16, 3))        // >> '-016'
console.log(fillZeroes(-1.456, 3))     // >> '-001.456'
console.log(fillZeroes(-456.53453, 6)) // >> '-000456.53453'
console.log(fillZeroes('Agent 7', 3))  // >> 'Agent 007'
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting in case this is what you are looking for, converts time remaining in milliseconds to a string like 00:04:21

```
function showTimeRemaining(remain){
  minute = 60 * 1000;
  hour = 60 * minute;
  //
  hrs = Math.floor(remain / hour);
  remain -= hrs * hour;
  mins = Math.floor(remain / minute);
  remain -= mins * minute;
  secs = Math.floor(remain / 1000);
  timeRemaining = hrs.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" + mins.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" + secs.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  return timeRemaining;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A silly recursive way is:

```
function paddingZeros(text, limit) {
  if (text.length < limit) {
    return paddingZeros("0" + text, limit);
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}
```

where the limit is the size you want the string to be.

Ex: `appendZeros("7829", 20) // 00000000000000007829`

Answer (score 1):

Here are five different ways to zero-fill a number in JavaScript:

1. `String.prototype.padStart()`:

   ```js
   let n = 1;
   let zerofilled = n.toString().padStart(6, '0');
   console.log(zerofilled);
   ```
2. String concatenation and slice:

   ```js
   let n = 1;
   let zerofilled = ('000000' + n).slice(-6);
   console.log(zerofilled);
   ```
3. String repeat:

   ```js
   let n = 1;
   let zerofilled = '0'.repeat(6 - n.toString().length) + n;
   console.log(zerofilled);
   ```
4. Convert to string and pad with Array join:

   ```js
   let n = 1;
   let zerofilled = Array(7).join('0') + n;
   console.log(zerofilled.slice(-6));
   ```
5. Convert to string and pad with Array fill:

   ```js
   let n = 1;
   let zerofilled = (Array(6).fill('0').join('') + n).slice(-6);
   console.log(zerofilled);
   ```

Each of these solutions achieves zero-filling, and the best one depends on factors like readability, performance, and personal preference in the context of your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to make the comment (but i don't have enough points) that the highest voted answer fails with negative numbers and decimals

```
function padNumber(n,pad) {
    p = Math.pow(10,pad);
    a = Math.abs(n);
    g = (n<0);
    return (a < p) ?  ((g ? '-' : '') + (p+a).toString().substring(1)) : n;
}

padNumber( -31.235, 5);

"-00031.235"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function zfill(num, len) {
  return(0 > num ? "-" : "") + (Math.pow(10, len) <= Math.abs(num) ? "0" + Math.abs(num) : Math.pow(10, len) + Math.abs(num)).toString().substr(1)
}
```

This handles negatives and situations where the number is longer than the field width. And floating-point.

Comment: Re *"And floating-point"*: What about some of the famous edge cases, like 0.015?

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberPadding(n, p) {
  n = n.toString();
  var len = p - n.length;
  if (len > 0) {
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
      n = '0' + n;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable-length padding function:

```
function addPaddingZeroes(value, nLength)
{
    var sValue = value + ''; // Converts to string

    if(sValue.length >= nLength)
        return sValue;
    else
    {
        for(var nZero = 0; nZero < nLength; nZero++)
            sValue = "0" + sValue;
        return (sValue).substring(nLength - sValue.length, nLength);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple short recursive function to achieve your proposal:

```
function padleft (YourNumber, OutputLength){
    if (YourNumber.length >= OutputLength) {
        return YourNumber;
    } else {
        return padleft("0" +YourNumber, OutputLength);
    }
}
```

- **YourNumber** is the input number.
- **OutputLength** is the preferred output number length (with 0 padding left).

This function will add 0 on the left if your input number length is shorter than the wanted output number length.

Answer (score 0):

A little math can give you a one-line function:

```
function zeroFill( number, width ) {
  return Array(width - parseInt(Math.log(number)/Math.LN10) ).join('0') + number;
}
```

That's assuming that `number` is an integer no wider than `width`. If the calling routine can't make that guarantee, the function will need to make some checks:

```
function zeroFill( number, width ) {
    var n = width - parseInt(Math.log(number)/Math.LN10);
    return (n < 0) ? '' + number : Array(n).join('0') + number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My contribution:

I'm assuming you want the total string length to include the 'dot'. If not it's still simple to rewrite to add an extra zero if the number is a float.

```
padZeros = function (num, zeros) {
        return (((num < 0) ? "-" : "") + Array(++zeros - String(Math.abs(num)).length).join("0") + Math.abs(num));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function zFill(n,l){
    return 
      (l > n.toString().length) ? 
        ( (Array(l).join('0') + n).slice(-l) ) : n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a little array solution within a two line function. It checks also if the leading zeros are less than the length of the number string.

```
function pad(num, z) {
    if (z < (num = num + '').length) return num;
    return Array(++z - num.length).join('0') + num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this post looking for a native solution. Since there isn't a built-in solution, here's my take on it:

```
function zerofill(number, width) {
    var num = '';
    while (width-- > 0) {
        num += '0';
    }

    return num.slice(0, - (number + '').length) + number + '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Lodash.

```js
var n = 1;

alert( _.padLeft(n, 2, 0) ); // 01

n = 10;

alert( _.padLeft(n, 2, 0) ); // 10
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 makes this fairly trivial:

```es6
function pad (num, length, countSign = true) {
  num = num.toString()
  let negative = num.startsWith('-')
  let numLength = negative && !countSign ? num.length - 1 : num.length
  if (numLength >= length) {
    return num
  } else if (negative) {
    return '-' + '0'.repeat(length - numLength) + num.substr(1)
  } else {
    return '0'.repeat(length - numLength) + num
  }
}

pad(42, 4)          === '0042'
pad(12345, 4)       === '12345'
pad(-123, 4)        === '-100'
pad(-123, 4, false) === '-0100'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, clearer, more readable syntax IMHO

```
"use strict";
String.prototype.pad = function( len, c, left ) {
    var s = '',
        c = ( c || ' ' ),
        len = Math.max( len, 0 ) - this.length,
        left = ( left || false );
    while( s.length < len ) { s += c };
    return ( left ? ( s + this ) : ( this + s ) );
}
Number.prototype.pad = function( len, c, left ) {
    return String( this ).pad( len, c, left );
}
Number.prototype.lZpad = function( len ) {
    return this.pad( len, '0', true );
}
```

This also results in less visual and readability glitches of the results than some of the other solutions, which enforce '0' as a character; answering my questions what do I do if I want to pad other characters, or on the other direction (right padding), whilst remaining easy to type, and clear to read. Pretty sure it's also the DRY'est example, with the least code for the actual leading-zero-padding function body (as the other dependent functions are largely irrelevant to the question).

The code is available for comment via gist from this github user (original source of the code)
https://gist.github.com/Lewiscowles1986/86ed44f428a376eaa67f

A note on console & script testing, numeric literals seem to need parenthesis, or a variable in order to call methods, so 2.pad(...) will cause an error, whilst (2).pad(0,'#') will not. This is the same for all numbers it seems

Answer (score 0):

This is an angular provider that I wrote, which makes use of @profitehlolz 's answer but employs memoization so that commonly used pad length-pad character combinations will not invoke the array build join needlessly:

```
angular.module('stringUtilities', [])
    .service('stringFunctions', [function() {
        this.padMemo={ };
        this.padLeft=function(inputString,padSize,padCharacter) {

            var memoKey=padSize+""+padCharacter;

            if(!this.padMemo[memoKey]) {

                this.padMemo[memoKey]= new Array(1 + padSize).join(padCharacter);
            }

           var pad=this.padMemo[memoKey];
           return (pad + inputString).slice(-pad.length);
       };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.pad = (num, length) => "0".repeat(length - num.toString().length) + num;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `npm` is available in your environment some of ready-made packages can be used: [www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/zeropad](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/zeropad).

I like [zero-fill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zero-fill).

Installation

```
$ npm install zero-fill
```

Usage

```
var zeroFill = require('zero-fill')

zeroFill(4, 1)      // '0001' 
zeroFill(4, 1, '#') // '###1' custom padding
zeroFill(4)(1)      // '0001' partials
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to do it:

```
function padStr(number, numDigits){
  return 
    (number < 0 ? '-':'') 
    + ((new Array(numDigits + 1).join("0"))
    + Math.abs(number)).slice(-numDigits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something in [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) (TypeScript) and perhaps someone can use it:

```
class Helper {
    /**
     * adds leading 0 and returns string if value is not minSize long,
     * else returns value as string
     *
     * @param {string|number} value
     * @param {number} minSize
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public static leadingNullString(value: string|number, minSize: number): string {
        if (typeof value == "number") {
            value = "" + value;
        }
        let outString: string = '';
        let counter: number = minSize - value.length;
        if (counter > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                outString += '0';
            }
        }
        return (outString + value);
    }
}
```

`Helper.leadingNullString(123, 2);` returns "123"

`Helper.leadingNullString(5, 2);` returns "05"

`Helper.leadingNullString(40,2);` returns "40"

The ecmaScript4 (JavaScript) transpilation looks like that:

```
var Helper = (function () {
    function Helper() {
    }
    Helper.leadingNullString = function (value, minSize) {
        if (typeof value == "number") {
            value = "" + value;
        }
        var outString = '';
        var counter = minSize - value.length;
        if (counter > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                outString += '0';
            }
        }
        return (outString + value);
    };
    return Helper;
}());
```

Comment: [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) is not [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript).

Answer (score 0):

A simple elegant solution, where n is the number and l is the length.

`function nFill (n, l) {return (l>n.toString().length)?((Array(l).join('0')+n).slice(-l)):n;}`

This keeps the length if it is over desired, as not to alter the number.

```js
n = 500;

console.log(nFill(n, 5));
console.log(nFill(n, 2));

function nFill (n, l) {return (l>n.toString().length)?((Array(l).join('0')+n).slice(-l)):n;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "over desired"?

Answer (score 0):

The following provides a quick and fast solution:

```js
function numberPadLeft(num , max, padder = "0"){
     return "" == (num += "") ? "" :
     ( dif = max - num.length, dif > 0 ?
     padder.repeat(dif < 0 ? 0 : dif) + num :
     num )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an absurd one-liner while writing a numeric base converter.

```js
// This is cursed
function p(i,w,z){z=z||0;w=w||8;i+='';var o=i.length%w;return o?[...Array(w-o).fill(z),...i].join(''):i;}

console.log(p(8675309));        // Default: pad w/ 0 to 8 digits
console.log(p(525600, 10));     // Pad to 10 digits
console.log(p(69420, 10, 'X')); // Pad w/ X to 10 digits
console.log(p(8675309, 4));     // Pad to next 4 digits
console.log(p(12345678));       // Don't pad if you ain't gotta pad
```

Or, in a form that doesn't quite as readily betray that I've sold my soul to the Black Perl:

```js
function pad(input, width, zero) {
    zero = zero || 0; width = width || 8;  // Defaults
    input += '';                           // Convert input to string first

    var overflow = input.length % width    // Do we overflow?
    if (overflow) {                        // Yep!  Let's pad it...
        var needed = width - overflow;     // ...to the next boundary...
        var zeroes = Array(needed);        // ...with an array...
        zeroes = zeroes.fill(zero);        // ...full of our zero character...
        var output = [...zeroes,...input]; // ...and concat those zeroes to input...
        output = output.join('');          // ...and finally stringify.
    } else {
        var output = input;                // We don't overflow; no action needed :)
    }

    return output;                         // Done!
}
```

One thing that sets this apart from the other answers is that it takes a *modulo* of the number's length to the target width rather than a simple greater-than check.  This is handy if you want to make sure the resulting length is some multiple of a target width (e.g., you need the output to be either 5 or 10 characters long).

I have no idea how well it performs, but hey, at least it's already minified!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick I think is cool:

```
(2/10000).toString().split(".")[1]
"0002"
(52/10000).toString().split(".")[1]
"0052"
```

Comment: This does not work with numbers which end in zero.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the problem interesting, I put my small contribution**

```js
function zeroLeftComplete(value, totalCharters = 3) {
    const valueString = value.toString() || '0'
    const zeroLength = valueString.length - totalCharters
    if (Math.sign(parseInt(zeroLength)) === -1) {
        const zeroMissing = Array.from({ length: Math.abs(zeroLength) }, () => '0').join('')
        return `${zeroMissing}${valueString}`
    } else return valueString

};
console.log(zeroLeftComplete(0));
console.log(zeroLeftComplete(1));
console.log(zeroLeftComplete(50));
console.log(zeroLeftComplete(50561,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with Intl.NumberFormat function:

```js
const num = 5;
const formattedNum = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumIntegerDigits: 6, useGrouping: false }).format(num);
console.log(formattedNum);
```

Answer (score -1):

Our tests were bogus because mine had a typo.

```
zeroPad = function (num, count) {
    return ((num / Math.pow(10, count)) + '').substr(2);
};
```

Paul's is the fastest, but I think .substr is faster than .slice even if it is one character more ;)

Answer (score -1):

To pad at the end of the number, use num.toFixed

for example:

```
  document.getElementById('el').value = amt.toFixed(2);
```

It's the simplest solution i've found, and it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
function numPadding (padding,i) {
    return padding.substr(0, padding.length - (Math.floor(i).toString().length)) + Math.floor(i );
}

numPadding("000000000",234); -> "000000234"
```

or

```
function numPadding (number, paddingChar,i) {
    var padding = new Array(number + 1).join(paddingChar);
    return padding.substr(0, padding.length - (Math.floor(i).toString().length)) + Math.floor(i );
}

numPadding(8 ,"0", 234); -> "00000234";
```

Answer (score -1):

I was here looking for a standard and had the same idea as Paul and Jonathan... Theirs are super cute, but here's a horrible-cute version:

```
function zeroPad(n, l, i) {
    return (i = n/Math.pow(10, l))*i > 1 ? '' + n : i.toFixed(l).replace('0.', '');
}
```

This works too (we're assuming integers, yes?)...

```
> zeroPad(Math.pow(2, 53), 20);
'00009007199254740992'

> zeroPad(-Math.pow(2, 53), 20);
'-00009007199254740992'

> zeroPad(Math.pow(2, 53), 10);
'9007199254740992'

> zeroPad(-Math.pow(2, 53), 10);
'-9007199254740992'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function uint_zerofill(num, width) {
    var pad = ''; num += '';
    for (var i = num.length; i < width; i++)
        pad += '0';
    return pad + num;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used

```
Utilities.formatString("%04d", iThe_TWO_to_FOUR_DIGIT)
```

which gives up to 4 leading 0s

NOTE:  THIS REQUIRES Google's apps-script Utilities:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate-args

Comment: This does not exist... if you're referring to util.format, it is simplistic and only supports %d, not %04d formatting like printf in "C".  Please remove this.

Comment: This worked for me. Your down rating now makes it impossible for me to do anything. @GroovyCakes. If you consider undoing whatever you did, I will refrain in the future from trying to help people on this forum. Had no idea about the intricacies of stackoverflow... safer for beginners just to ask questions.

Answer (score -2):

Mnah...  I have not seen a "ultimate" answer to this issue and if you are facing the same challenge I must save you some time by saying that sadly there's not built-in function for that on JavaScript.

But there's **[this awesome function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)** in PHP that does a great job on padding strings as well as numbers with single character or arbitrary strings. After some time of banging my head for not having the right tool on JavaScript (mostly for zerofillin' numbers and usually for trimming strings to fit a fixed length) and excessive coding work, I decided to write my own function.

It does the same ("almost the same"; read on for detail) that the dream PHP function does, but in comfortable client-side JavaScript:

```
function str_pad(input, pad_length, pad_string, pad_type) {
    var input = input.toString();
    var output = "";

    if((input.length > pad_length) &&
       (pad_type == 'STR_PAD_RIGHT')) {

        var output = input.slice(0, pad_length);
    }
    else
        if((input.length > pad_length) &&
           (pad_type == 'STR_PAD_LEFT')) {

            var output = input.slice(input.length -
                                     pad_length,input.length);
        }
        else
            if((input.length < pad_length) &&
               (pad_type == 'STR_PAD_RIGHT')) {

                var caracteresNecesarios = pad_length-input.length;
                var rellenoEnteros = Math.floor(caracteresNecesarios/pad_string.length);
                var rellenoParte = caracteresNecesarios%pad_string.length;
                var output = input;
                for(var i=0; i<rellenoEnteros; i++) {
                    var output = output + pad_string;
                };
                var output = output + pad_string.slice(0, rellenoParte);
            }
            else
                if((input.length < pad_length) &&
                   (pad_type=='STR_PAD_LEFT')) {

                    var caracteresNecesarios = pad_length-input.length;
                    var rellenoEnteros = Math.floor(caracteresNecesarios/pad_string.length);
                    var rellenoParte = caracteresNecesarios%pad_string.length;
                    var output = "";
                    for(var i=0; i<rellenoEnteros; i++) {
                        var output = output + pad_string;
                    };
                    var output = output + pad_string.slice(0, rellenoParte);
                    var output = output + input;
                }
                else
                    if(input.length == pad_length) {
                        var output = input;
                    };
    return output;
};
```

The only thing that my function does not do is the `STR_PAD_BOTH` behavior that I could add with some time and a more comfortable keyboard.
You might call the function and test it; bet you'll love it if you don't mind that inner code uses one or two words in Spanish... not big deal I think. I did not added comments for "watermarking" my coding so you can seamless use it in your work nor I compressed the code for enhanced readability.
Use it and test it like this and *spread the code*:

```
alert("str_pad('murcielago', 20, '123', 'STR_PAD_RIGHT')=" + str_pad('murcielago', 20, '123', 'STR_PAD_RIGHT') + '.');
```

Comment: downvoted because I'm not fond of supporting the idea that one function should consider everything and be "ultimate". Yes, it may be robust and that *could* be times for that, but typically it creates clutter and reduces efficiency. To each their own though.

Comment: probably the worst function ever written

Answer (score -3):

```
function zeroPad(num,digits){ return ((num/Math.pow(10,digits))+'').slice(2) }
```

Comment: this has a couple of issues: it trims off zeroes from the right `zeroPad(50, 5) == "0005"`, and trims off numbers from the left if it's longer than the padding width: `zeroPad(123456, 5) == "23456"`